# Is it possible to track redirect event without tracking click on a button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tracking

I am redirecting after form submission.

But form is in iframe, so I can't track it submission.

Is it possible to track my redirection after form submission?

Also I see message in console

Navigated to https://events.genndi.com/thankyou/1d89404d09?req=8r122534042ok

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use **hashchange**

```
window.addEventListener("hashchange", funcRef, false);
```

You can read more about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onhashchange

Litle example with jQuery :

```
$(window).on('hashchange', function() {
        // type your code here
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
$('a').live('click', function () {
     $.post('/registerclick/', { data: $(this).attr('src') }, function () {});
});
```

$('a').live('click', function () {
       $.post('/registerclick/', { data: $(this).attr('src') }, function () {}); });

Comment: not helping. site is https://seriouslevity.net/webinar, after form submission you will be redirected. I need to track this redirect